# Mesh slicing/knifing with multiple planes

Tags: c++, mathematics, 3d-meshes, mesh

I have a ginormous mesh which I want to cut with multiple planes.
For simplicity I want to know how to cut a mesh with single plane and repeat the logic.

Consider a `X-Y` plane of coords `(1,1,0,0) = (a,b,c,d)`, from the equation `ax+by+cz+d`, which is the equation of the plane.

How shall I use this information to cut a mesh? Any help will be invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

Find all triangles that intersect with the plane, split them into two polygons and triangulate the polygons.

If you want a cap, enumerate all vertices generated from the slice and create a cap to fill the possibly concave planar hole.

The devil is in the edge cases where you go exactly through vertices and edges, so make sure to robustly handle those.